# Supremum of a finite power series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I'm trying to prove that the supremum of $\sum a^{x_{i}}$ given $\sum x_{i} = c$ and where $c$ is a positive constant, $x_{i} \geq 0$, and $a \geq1$, is when $(x_i)$ are all zero except one which would be equal to $c$.

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

$x \mapsto a^x$ is a convex function since $a \ge 1$, so we can use Jensen's inequality to show that we can 'move points further apart while keeping their sum the same' to increase the total value of the function. We can look for a finite procedure to do this to an arbitrary starting set of points until it becomes the equality case we know. One way is to pick any 2 non-zero points and move them apart until one becomes zero. This is always possible because all the points are non-negative. We only need to repeat this at most $n-1$ times where $n$ is the number of points, and then we are done.

Comment: This technique is called "smoothing" and can be applied to many kinds of inequalities, although it is generally easier to use when the objective function is a sum of function values where the function has only one or two inflection points.